# rails 4 change font everywhere in the app

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, fonts

I would like to change the standard font for my Rails app, and use a new font for every view in the app.
As a try, I downloaded the custom Delicious font from [here](http://www.exljbris.com/delicious.html)

And copied the downloaded file in the /assets/fonts/ folder of my app.
I added these rows in my config/application.rb:

```
config.assets.enabled = true  
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"
```

and I modified my custom.css.scss file adding this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Delicious';
  src: url('/assets/Delicious-Roman.otf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Delicious';
  font-weight: bold;
  src: url('/assets/Delicious-Bold.otf');
}
```

I tried to use the font in a view of the app calling the font in the css class for the specific view in this way,

```
.products-index {
  background-image: image-url("mag.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Delicious";
}
```

and it works, but I don't want to create a css class for all the views in my app. I tried to specify the font in a single point of the css, adding this row in my custom.css.scss:

```
html {font-family: "Delicious";}
```

But it doesn't work. How can I modify my css to select the font for all the app?

I'm using Bootstrap3, in my custom.css.scss I have, at the very top, the row

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: my rails app uses a custom font, but we placed the @font-face in application.scss, not in a custom css file.

Comment: I have an application.css.sass, in which I have statements  *= require rails_bootstrap_forms
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self     Where I can put the @font-face?

Answer (score 4):

I solved! I put
`

```
* {
  font-family: "Delicious";
 }
```

in my custom.css.scss file, so the * means that the font is used for all the elements